# Changing v-text-field background component on @change event

Tags: vuetify.js

My goal is to change the color of the vuetify v-text-field component to a different color when the input value has changed.

I've tried using the @change event in the vuetify controller but it only passes the text value in the event so there's no way for me to bind any additional classes to the actual component.

I could obviously have booleans for each specific control and have each @change event access these separately, but I was hoping for a more reusable/generic way to do this.

```
<template>
  <v-text-field
    label="Project"
    @changed="updateBackground"
  ></v-text-field>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      changeBackground(event) {
        //change background color of component with props here?
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED :**

Looks like you want to modify the element properties such as adding classes...etc ... for that you can bind `ref` attribute to your input and then manipulate that element on your method like :

```js
updateBackground() {
    // nextTick is when the DOM gets updated
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.$refs.input.$el.classList.remove('red')
      this.$refs.input.$el.classList.add('blue')
    });
```

and on your template :

```
<v-text-field 
      ref="input"
      label="Project"
      @change="updateBackground"
      class="red"
></v-text-field>
```

Here is a working sample : https://codepen.io/Dadboz/pen/PMjbgW

Comment: This would work, but the issue would be I would need to create a separate back style variable for each component I wanted to keep track of. I was hoping for a more generic approach where I would be able to actually add and remove either a new css class or directly bind due to component style property.